# android - Расскажите про импорты и библиотеки

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

Здравствуйте, меня уже давно мучают два вопроса:

1) Например, имеется импорт

```
import android.widget.*;
```

Он импортирует **все** виджеты в android. Это как нибудь влияет на размер приложения? Если да, то значит правильно писать импорты нужно так

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

Или это вообще не важно?

2) Например, мне нужен какой-нибудь виджет из библиотеки. Могу ли я подключить лишь именно его, а не всю библиотеку? Или это не повлияет на размер приложения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Импорты не влияют на вес приложения. Импорты нужны для предотвращения конфликтов меж классами с одинаковыми именами. Все классы которые вы можете импортировать уже включены в ваше приложение